# jPlayer progress bar knob

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jplayer

I was recently working with jPlayer and I want the play bar ("jp-play-bar") to have a little knob in the right side when streaming, like the one in this pic:
[image: Desired progress bar behavior]

Yet, when I try to set the background, the image is sliced and contained within the borders of the progress bar (jp-progress). How could I set it to pop up without breaking the other visuals? Has somebody tried?

Here's the demo version from their official website: http://www.jplayer.org/latest/demo-01

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just had a fiddle around and came up with:

http://jsfiddle.net/gRoberts/BNt3m/

With a little more tweaking, it should be very simple to replicate what you need.

You could also then use the `$.jPlayer.event.timeupdate` event to create the time bubble should you want to.

Comment: Wow! This is brilliant! Thank you very much, it's exactly what I've needed. You just saved me some precious, precious time. Cheers!

Comment: Glad it was of some use. I'd suggest a little more testing, as I had to change the `overflow` property of a few elements that had them specifically set to `hidden`. In another browser it may not render as expect.